# Getting coordinates of neighbours in two-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am looking for a way to get coordinates of neighbours in two dimensional array.
The problem I'm facing is that I want to define number of distant neighbours.
I know how to get immediate 8 neighbours using vectors like:

```
var distance = 1;
var top_left = array[x-distance ][y-distance ];
```

...and so on. But I want to get wider range of neighbours like in this code snippet.

```js
var Move = function() {

  var that = this;

  this.grid = {
    width: 12,
    height: 12
  };

  this.showMoveableTiles = function() {
    var movableTiles = 3;
    var row = $(this).data('row');
    var tile = $(this).data('tile');

    $('.tile').removeClass('moveable');

    $('#grid .tile').filter(function() {
      return Math.abs($(this).data('row') - row) <= movableTiles && Math.abs($(this).data('tile') - tile) <= movableTiles && !($(this).data('row') == row && $(this).data('tile') == tile)
    }).addClass('moveable');
  };

};

var makeGrid = function(width, height) {
  var tiles = '';

  for (var row = 0; row < height; row++) {
    for (var tile = 1; tile <= width; tile++) {
      tiles += '<div class="tile" data-tile="' + tile + '" data-row="' + (row + 1) + '"></div>';
    }
  }

  $('#grid').append(tiles);
};

var move = new Move();

makeGrid(10, 10);

$(document).on('mousedown', '.tile', move.showMoveableTiles);
```

```css
#grid {
  width: 300px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tile {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #777;
  outline: 1px solid goldenrod;
  float: left;
}

.tile:hover {
  background-color: #999;
}

.moveable {
  background-color: #add8e6;
}

.moveable:hover {
  background-color: #c8ebf7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="grid"></div>
```

Comment: the code snippet isn't helping me to understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Is this the relevant logic in the code you're currently using?

    `$('#grid .tile').filter(function() {
        return Math.abs($(this).data('row') - row) <= movableTiles &&
            Math.abs($(this).data('tile') - tile) <= movableTiles && 
            !($(this).data('row') == row && 
            $(this).data('tile') == tile)
    }).addClass('moveable');`

This seems reasonable. Is it not working? Are you forgetting to remove the 'moveable' class when changing the $(this) tile being analyzed?

Comment: This snippet is good, besides returning the coordinates in 2D array ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `slice` to cut chunks out of your 2d-array. To determine which parts you need, you calculate which rows and which columns are in the area.

Say you have a point at `x: 3, y: 5`, and want an area of `size: 2` around this location, you'll calculate:

```
var topRow = y - size;
var bottomRow = y + size;
var leftColumn = x - size;
var rightColumn = x + size;
```

Now, you can loop through your rows and slice each row using `row.slice(leftColumn, rightColumn + 1)`

The example below shows how its done, but I haven't incorporated your exact example. Also, it won't work for coordinates that are too close to the edge of the grid to handle the required size. I'll leave it up to you to fix that. (Also, it's in ES6)

```js
const getArea = (x, y, s, grid) => {
  const topRow = y - s;
  const bottomRow = y + s;
  const leftCol = x - s;
  const rightCol = x + s;
  
  const gridArea = [];
  
  for (let r = topRow; r <= bottomRow; r += 1) {
    gridArea.push(grid[r].slice(leftCol, rightCol + 1));
  }
  
  return gridArea;
}


const tenxTen = makeGrid(10, 10);

// Get one element
logGrid(getArea(0, 0, 0, tenxTen));

// Get 3x3 around x:1, y:1 (b1)
logGrid(getArea(1, 1, 1, tenxTen));

// Get 7x7 around x:5, y:5 (f5)
logGrid(getArea(5, 5, 3, tenxTen));



// Utils
function makeRow(i, w) {
  return Array.from(Array(w), (_, j) => 
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[i] + (j));
};

function makeGrid(w, h) {
  return Array.from(Array(h), (_, i) => makeRow(i, w))
};

function logGrid(grid) {
  console.log(grid.map(r => r.join("|")));
}
```

Comment: I guess I will have to get to know the slice function - but it looks like a legit answer. Thank You